# Unable to set cookie on Internet Explorer via Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I have seen alot of questions regarding this and alot of different answers, but none of them that I can see either apply to me or I have tried and they have failed.

So, essentially I have the below code:

```
Date.prototype.addMins = function(minutes) { 
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + minutes*60000); 
  return this; 
}

function readCookie(name) { 
  var nameEQ = name + "="; 
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); 
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) { 
    var c = ca[i]; 
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length); 
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c; 
   } 
   return null; 
}

var timer_expiry = new Date().addMins(1);
var expiry = new Date().setFullYear(2030);

document.cookie = 'my_signup_clock='+timer_expiry+';expires='+expiry+';path=/;';

var asc = readCookie('my_signup_clock')

if (asc) { 
 alert("exists");
} else{ 
 alert("does not");
}
```

I've tested this on all my browsers and the cookies are set except for Internet Explorer (including 11).  Below is what I think would help rule out certain answers:

1. my domain is not less than 2 characters
2. my domain does not have any underscores in it
3. my cookies should be 'first-party' there are no iframes being called on the website
4. my website is not P3P set (but I believe this is not a requirement?)
5. my IE browser is default settings (I'm on Mac so I view the website via VMs or BrowserStack) - so the answer 'change your settings' won't be accepted, as I need to think of my users.
6. my website redirects all http into https (if that helps)

If anyone has any ideas how to troubleshoot this that would be great because unfortunately I can't see how the heck I'll be able to do this - I must be doing something wrong.

Many Thanks

Comment: Try using the method on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie